# Unable to correctly install pip3 using apt-get

Tags: apt, python, python3, pip

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and was experiencing issues with my pip3. Specifically, when I attempted to uninstall a package via

```
sudo pip3 uninstall
```

I encountered

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I attempted to resolve this issue by reinstalling pip3, specifically

```
 sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

which succeeded. However, I no longer have a local version of pip3 at all

```
bash: /home/kurt/.local/bin/pip3: No such file or directory
```

Using `which pip3` in a new terminal I find,

```
$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

and attempting to use pip3 at all brings me

```
$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

However, I am able to execute without incident when typing `sudo -H pip3 -v`. Reinstalling pip3 from apt, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip --reinstall
```

has no effect. If anyone has any insight, or has encountered a similar problem, I would greatly appreciate any input on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Use `type` instead of `which`. Try `type pip3` instead, and see if the output is different.

Comment: As a user, I get `pip3 is hashed (/usr/bin/pip3)`. As sudo (with or without -H) I get `pip3 is /usr/bin/pip3`.

Comment: Run `hash -r` then try `pip3` again.

Comment: After running `hash -r`, `type` as user gives me `pip3 is /usr/bin/pip3`. However attempting to use `pip3` as user results in the same error. Entering `type pip3` subsequent to this failure results in the original message, `pip3 is hashed (/usr/bin/pip3)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After uninstalling pip3 using

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
```

I deleted the directory

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-pacakges
```

and reinstalled pip3 using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This appears to have resolved the issue. I no longer receive the aforementioned error when attempting to use `pip3` or `sudo pip3`. Rather, `pip3 -V`, `sudo pip3 -V`, and `sudo -H pip3 -V` all identically and sucessfully return

```
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: For me the directory was `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`; removing it make `pip3` work again. I had previously installed `tensorflow` and `matplotlib`; that seem to have broken it.