# How can I use pip3?

Tags: 18.04, python3, pip

If I try to use `pip3` I see:

```
$ pip3 --version

Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-pip
```

So I run:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Then:

```
$ pip3 --version

Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Are the instructions just wrong?

Comment: Try reinstalling pip3 with `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip`.

Comment: Try calling it with sudo, `sudo pip3 --version`. Bad idea, but perhaps it's only available to root for some reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correctly install pip3 using apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076152/unable-to-correctly-install-pip3-using-apt-get)

Comment: The solution is the same but the problem I was encountering was different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it following the instructions from this solution to [Unable to correctly install pip3 using apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076387/59832):

> Uninstall pip3 using
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
> ```
>
> Delete the directory

```
 $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages  # (python3.6 instead of 3.5)
```

> Reinstall pip3 using apt-get
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python3-pip
> ```

Answer (score 0):

after this I did:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then pip3 -V   replied: pip 20.2.2 from /home/…